# How do I convert my subclass to its base class properly when generics are involved?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm attempting to override a base property like so:

```
public class Node {}
public class SubNode : Node { }

public class NodeViewModel<T> where T : Node
{
    public virtual T Data { get; set; }
}
public class SubNodeViewModel : NodeViewModel<SubNode>
{
    public override SubNode Data { get; set; }
}

...
List<NodeViewModel<Node>> l = new List<NodeViewModel<Node>>();
l.Add(new SubNodeViewModel()); // Cannot convert from SubNodeViewModel to NodeViewModel<Node>
...
```

I think I must be misunderstanding a fundamental of inheritance. Why am I not able to do this?

I guess I'm confused as to why this works:

```
Node node;
SubNode subnode;
node = subnode; // I work just fine!
```

But not this:

```
NodeViewModel<Node> node;
SubNodeViewModel subnode;
node = subnode; // I don't work. Also, I hate you!
```

Comment: Just remove `public override SubNode Data { get; set; }` and you have what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your `NodeViewModel<T>` class is not covariant. Whether you can do this depends on the operations you need to support, but for the code in your question you can create an interface:

```
public interface INodeViewModel<out T> where T : Node
{
    T Data { get; }
}
```

then implement it

```
public NodeViewModel<T> : INodeViewModel<T> where T : Node { ... }
```

then change the type of the items in `l`:

```
List<INodeViewModel<Node>> l = new List<INodeViewModel<Node>>();
```

Comment: Thank you, interfaces work great - and the quick code snippet was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You are not able to do this because `NodeViewModel<T>` is not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on its type argument `T`: `NodeViewModel<Node>` is not the "base class" of `NodeViewModel<SubNode>`, even if `Node` *is* the base of `SubNode`. Technically this has nothing to do with inheritance.

If you want to have all kinds of `NodeViewModel` in the same list the only way to do that is by using a common interface or base class as the type argument of the list.